# Ruby on Rails: [404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi everyone I am running my project in localhost and I have implemented a small search bar in which by entering the name of a city the activities present in the city appear on a map but every time I start the search I have this type of error.
I can't understand if it's due to the fact that some data is missing in the db or some code bug

This is the stack trace:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound - [404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [eateries_development]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"eateries_development","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"eateries_development"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [eateries_development]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"eateries_development","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"eateries_development"},"status":404}:
  elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:202:in `__raise_transport_error'
  elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:319:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-api (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb:183:in `search'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/query.rb:198:in `execute_search'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:13:in `block in execute_search'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:12:in `execute_search'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/query.rb:81:in `execute'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick.rb:100:in `search'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/model.rb:29:in `searchkick_search'
  app/models/eatery_search.rb:8:in `search'
  app/facades/search_page.rb:14:in `eateries'
  app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:16:in `show'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/route_translator-9d3350d9574c/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:27:in `set_locale_from_url'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.7.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  bullet (5.5.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

Started POST "/__better_errors/add52783cdc3b8c6/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-11-21 18:28:34 +0100
```

this is the model:

```
class EaterySearch
  def initialize(params, req = nil)
    @req = req
    @params = params
  end

  def search
    Eatery.search name, where: search_params
  end

  def search_params
    {
      location: location_query,
      reviewed: reviewed_query,
      opening_days: today,
      category_id: categories,
      visible: true
    }.reject { |k,v| v.nil? }
  end

  def today
    return Time.now.wday if @params[:open_today]
  end

  def reviewed_query
    if @params[:only_reviewed]
      true
    end
  end

  def location_query
    return nil unless position
    {
      near: position,
      within: "#{distance}km"
    }
  end

  def position
    if (@params[:location])
      geo = Geocoder.search(location)
      if geo.any?
        { lat: geo.first.data["geometry"]["location"]["lat"], lon: geo.first.data["geometry"]["location"]["lng"] }
      end
    else
      { lat: user_location.split(', ')[0], lon: user_location.split(', ')[1] }
    end
  end

  def name
    return "*" unless @params[:name]
    @params[:name].empty? ? "*" : @params[:name]
  end

  def location
    @params[:location]
  end

  def user_location
    @params[:user_location]
  end

  def distance
    @params[:distance] || 200
  end

  def categories
    return nil unless @params[:category_ids]
    category_ids = @params[:category_ids].reject{ |c| c.to_s.empty? }
    if category_ids != ["*"]
      category_ids
    end
    if category_ids.include? "*" && category_ids.count > 1
      category_ids - ["*"]
    end
  end
end
```

this is the search_page.rb

```
class SearchPage
  attr_accessor :params

  def initialize(user, req, params)
    @user = user
    @req = req
    @params = params
  end

  def eateries
    if sanitize_params.except(:distance).empty?
      EmptySearch.new
    else
      @eateries ||= EaterySearch.new(sanitize_params, @req).search
    end
  end

  def open_today
    sanitize_params[:open_today]
  end

  def location
    sanitize_params[:location]
  end

  def user_location
    sanitize_params[:user_location]
  end

  def map_center
    if (@params[:location])
      geo = Geocoder.search(location)
      if geo.any?
        { lat: geo.first.data["geometry"]["location"]["lat"], lng: geo.first.data["geometry"]["location"]["lng"] }
      end
    elsif user_location
      { lat: user_location.split(', ')[0], lon: user_location.split(', ')[1] }
    end
  end

  def distance
    params[:distance]
  end

  def name
    sanitize_params[:name]
  end

  def category_ids
    if @params[:category_ids]
      sanitize_params[:category_ids].reject{ |c| c.to_s.empty? }
    end
  end

  def allergen_ids
    if @params[:allergen_ids]
      sanitize_params[:allergen_ids].reject{|a| a.to_s.empty? }
    end
  end

  def food_typology_ids
    if @params[:food_typology_ids]
      if @params[:food_typology_ids] != ["", "*"]
        sanitize_params[:food_typology_ids].reject{|a| a.to_s.empty? }
      end
    end
  end

  def only_reviewed
    sanitize_params[:only_reviewed]
  end

  def sanitize_params
    @sanitize_params ||= @params.each do |k, v|
      if v == "1"
        @params[k] = true
      end
      if v == "0"
        @params[k] = false
      end
      if v == ""
        @params[k] = nil
      end
    end.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v == false }
  end
end
```

this is the search_controller

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:ajax_results]
  skip_before_action :set_locale, only: [:ajax_results]


  require 'RMagick'
  require 'rvg/rvg'
  include Magick

  def show
    redirect_to controller: 'cities', action: 'show', location: searchkick_params[:location] if searchkick_params[:location]
    @page = SearchPage.new(current_user, request, searchkick_params)
    
    
    js search_results: @page.eateries, map_center: @page.map_center, ajax_results_url: api_v1_search_map_results_path, search_allergens: @page.allergen_ids, search_food_typologies: @page.food_typology_ids
  end

  def map_pointer
    text_to_write = params[:number]

    magick_image = Magick::ImageList.new
    magick_image.new_image(30, 30, Magick::HatchFill.new('transparent', 'transparent'))

    circle = Magick::Draw.new
    circle.fill('#E66747')
    circle.circle(15,15,5.5,5.5)
    circle.draw(magick_image)

    circle = Magick::Draw.new
    circle.fill('#FFFFFF')
    circle.circle(15,15,7,7)
    circle.draw(magick_image)

    circle = Magick::Draw.new
    circle.fill('#E66747')
    circle.circle(15,15,8,8)
    circle.draw(magick_image)


    if text_to_write != 'false'
      txt = Magick::Draw.new
      magick_image.annotate(txt, 0,0,1,1, text_to_write){
        txt.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
        txt.font = 'Helvetica'
        txt.pointsize = 12
        txt.fill = '#ffffff'
        txt.font_weight = 800
      }
    end
    
    data = Magick::Image.from_blob( magick_image.to_blob { self.format = "png" } )

    send_data data[0].to_blob, :filename => "woohoo.png", :disposition => 'inline', :quality => 90, :type => 'image/png'
  end

  def search_params
    params.permit(
      :sw_lng, :sw_lat, :ne_lng, :ne_lat
    )
  end

  def searchkick_params
    if params[:search]
      params.require(:search).permit(
        :name, :location, :open_today, :only_reviewed, :distance, category_ids: [], allergen_ids: [], food_typology_ids: []
      )
    else
      geo = Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first.data["city"]
      if geo.empty?
        {}
      else
        { location: geo }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in the model the compiler reports me a problem in this function:

```
  def search

    Eatery.search name, where: search_params

  end
```

in the SearchPage the compiler reports me a problem in this function:

```
  def eateries

    if sanitize_params.except(:distance).empty?

      EmptySearch.new

    else

      @eateries ||= EaterySearch.new(sanitize_params, @req).search

    end

  end
```

in the SearchController the compiler reports me a problem in this line:

```
js search_results: @page.eateries, map_center: @page.map_center, ajax_results_url: api_v1_search_map_results_path, search_allergens: @page.allergen_ids, search_food_typologies: @page.food_typology_ids
```

Gemfile:

```
########## Elasticsearch
gem 'searchkick'
```

Comment: `"no such index [eateries_development]"` seems to point to a missing Elasticsearch index in your dev environment. Do you see the index when you run something like `curl -I "localhost:9200/eateries_development?pretty"`?

Comment: I tried to run the command but got this result "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 598"

Comment: I would double check if you have Elasticsearch running locally, and see if you can get an overview of the indices that exist. The command for that depends on your version of Elasticsearch. For the latest version, you can find `curl` commands here: [cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/cat-indices.html).

Comment: this is my version curl 7.65.3